# Passing Value of Input into JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, forms

I am having trouble passing input values into a JavaScript function that takes two values and multiplies them. When I hard-code my numbers in, it works just fine. But, when I try to use the input values, I don't get anything - not even `undefined`. Here's my code:

```js
function multiply (val1, val2) {
   var n = val1;
   for(var i = 1; i < val2; i++) {
     n += val1;
   }
   return n;
}

var result = multiply(document.getElementById('first').value, document.getElementById('second').value);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<h1>Mutiplication Algorithm</h1>

<p>This algorithm attempts to multiply to given values without ever using the <span>*</span> operator</p>

<input id="first" type="text" value=5 /> x
<input type="text" value=4 /> =
<span id="result"></span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Input values are always strings.

Comment: But, even when I pass them as integers, it does not work.

Comment: Show an example of how you "pass them as integers" and maybe I'd believe you. The fact is, whether or not you quote the `value` attribute, using [the `value` property of an HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review your code again. You didn't have your second input id parameter. Then if you want to treat values as integers, simply parse them as int :) Look at code below

```js
function multiply (val1, val2) {
   val1 = parseInt(val1);
   var n = val1;
   for(var i = 1; i < val2; i++) {
     n += val1;
   }
   return n;
}

var result = multiply(document.getElementById('first').value, document.getElementById('second').value);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<h1>Mutiplication Algorithm</h1>

<p>This algorithm attempts to multiply to given values without ever using the <span>*</span> operator</p>

<input id="first" type="text" value=5 /> x
<input type="text" id="second" value="4" /> =
<span id="result"></span>
```